# Get balance of other people

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm basically trying to making a balance command (with quick.db) that checks for yourself and for other people as well, suppose -bal
(my balance pop up) but then when I ping someone with -bal @(user) it shows my current balance as well, here's an image:

[image]

I've also tried lots of ways but it seems to not work for me :/

Here's the code:

```js
let bal =
  db.fetch(`money_${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}`) ||
  db.fetch(`money_${message.guild.id}_${message.mentions.users.first()}`);

if (bal === null) bal = 0;

let user = message.mentions.users.first().username || message.author.username;

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('[ ' + user + "'s balance ]")
  .setDescription(bal);
message.channel.send(embed);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the order of values when you declare the `bal` variable. You're basically saying that if there is a `message.author` then `bal`'s value will be their balance. As there is always a message author, you will never check the mentioned user. So, you need to change the order.

Or, you could also simplify it like I did below. You can create a new `user` variable and if there is a mentioned user, assign its value, if not, assign the author. Later, as both the mentioned user and the author has an `id` and a `username`, you can simply use `user.id` and `user.username`.

You can also simplify the `if (bal === null) bal = 0` part, by simply using a logical OR (`||`) after the `db.fetch`.

```js
let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
let balance = db.fetch(`money_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`) || 0;

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('[ ' + user.username + "'s balance ]")
  .setDescription(balance);
message.channel.send(embed);
```